# Not able to update Identity AspNetUsers table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to build a 9gag-like site.

I have the following models:

```
public class Meme
{
    public Meme()
    {
        CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
        Comments = new List<Comment>();
    }
    public int MemeId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Tags { get; set; }

    public string Url { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public byte[] Buffer { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    public int Views { get; set; }
    public int Upvotes { get; set; }
    public int Downvotes { get; set; }

    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    public int CommentId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int Upvotes { get; set; }
    public int Downvotes { get; set; }
    public int MemeId { get; set; }
    public Meme Meme { get; set; }
 }


public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
            Memes = new List<Meme>();
    }
    public List<Meme> Memes { get; set; }
}
```

What I did afterwards was to add a migration and update the database. No errors there, everything seems normal. However, the `AspNetUsers` table does not have any columns added. I've checked several tutorials on how to edit the `AspNetUsers` table and all suggest doing the things I've done. I'm obviously missing something.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the SO ! The models you have included shouldn't be related with the problem you describe. You say that `AspNetUsers` does not have any _columns_. Propably you mean that there aren't any records (rows) in the table. Correct ? If so, the problem is that you haven't create any user yet. If you have used the asp.net mvc template, that is provided by visual studio, when you go to create a new project and select web application etc., then you would have a controller called Account. Furthermore there should be also some view for registering a user.

Comment: Hey, no, that is not what I meant. But I'm really bad at databases still so maybe I just got confused. Maybe I'm not doing it properly and I should just include a UserId in the Meme model, so that it points to a certain User, am I correct ? Cause I've currently been trying to add a column to User, which I don't believe is correct at all.

Comment: What column did you expect the migration to add to `ApplicationUser`? This should only add a FK in `Meme`.